# Google sheets: Parse date from text

Tags: regex, date, parsing, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

## Google Sheets - Parsing

From given text, how do you extract the date?

| Given text | Extracted date (to be generated) |
| --- | --- |
| Graduation reunion on Saturday, September 10, 2022 at 123 Front Street | September 10, 2022 |
| BBQ Party on Sunday October 1, 2022 at 213 South Street | October 1, 2022 |

[Google Sheets link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cD9GG7WePL3Pre2jNFh6_Fp-7hl00RWiJ81NdVVasb0/edit?usp=sharing)

--

I've tried

```
=regexextract(A2,"\w{9} \d{2}, \d{4}")*1
```

As shown in the [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cD9GG7WePL3Pre2jNFh6_Fp-7hl00RWiJ81NdVVasb0/edit?usp=sharing), this only works for the first one which is September 10, 2022. However, not all months have the same number of characters.

Comment: See  [Should I include tags in title?](/help/tagging)

Comment: What is the general format on the text? Do the months have always a comma before or a Day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(\w+ \d+, \d{4})")*1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You may use either of the below:

Here, you have to drag down for the formula to populate below

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,", (.*?) at")
```

while the code below, will automatically expand on the column

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="","",REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,", (.*?) at")))
```

The formula, will take the characters after the first comma until 'at'.

[image]